# Using the count in Python Add a Character in the result?

Tags: python, count, string-length

Can someone explain me the following :-

Suppose i have this String variable

```
pcalpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Writing this piece of code `print(len(pcalpha))` will result in an output of an **int** which is equal to **26** which from my understanding means that the string has 26 characters in it.

Writing this other piece of code `print(pcalpha.count(""))` shall also give the same result according to the logic am following, but it is **not**. Can someone tell me why is it showing **27**?

Comment: Related: [Replacing the empty strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14431731/674039)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition is that there is a `""` after each letter and one before the first letter. So if you have 26 letters, that means you have 26 `""` plus the one at the beginning 26 + 1 = 27. For an example, let's replace "" by "-":

```
pcalpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print(pcalpha.replace("", "-"))
```

**Output**

```
-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m-n-o-p-q-r-s-t-u-v-w-x-y-z-
```

**Further**

1. For the implementation details, as mentioned by @RandomDavis, see
   [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a80af770870937271865b5e2b05a2cfe40b024b6/Objects/stringlib/count.h#L17).
2. [Replacing the empty strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14431731/674039)

Comment: To see why it returns 27 instead of 26, you can see the implementation here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a80af770870937271865b5e2b05a2cfe40b024b6/Objects/stringlib/count.h#L17

Comment: Yeah sure, i will refer to that as soon as i advance in the subject, currently i can barely understand anything.

Comment: If i may ask, what does the "" actually mean in python?

Comment: @SaifYsn It means the empty string

Comment: There is an argument that there are an infinite number of instances of the empty string.